# cannot ping link-local address from other subnet when defaut gateway route is seted

Tags: networking, debian, bonjour, zeroconf, avahi

i have a problem with my route table i dont know why it doesnt work.

I have two test cases, i did draw a network map for each case.

**currently i cant resolv the goal**.

[testcase-1 network map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LePdC.png)

[testcase-2 network map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwy95.png)

> The goal:

1. laptop-1 can ping raspberry pi **over zeroconf ip**
2. laptop-2 can ping raspberry pi **over zeroconf ip**
3. raspberry pi can ping 8.8.8.8 **over the default route**

> testcase-1

**the default gateway on raspberry pi's eth0 is 192.168.15.180**

- Laptop-1 can ping raspi **over zeroconf ip**
- Laptop-2 **cannot** ping raspi **over zeroconf ip**
- raspi can ping 8.8.8.8 **over the default route**

  Routing table

  ```
  default via 192.168.15.180 dev eth0
  default dev eth0  scope link  metric 1000
  169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 169.254.218.78
  169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1000
  192.168.15.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.15.6
  ```

> testcase-2

**no default gateway on raspberry pi's eth0**

- Laptop-1 can ping raspi **over zeroconf ip**
- Laptop-2 can ping raspi **over zeroconf ip**
- raspi **cant** ping 8.8.8.8 **over the default route**

  Routing table

  ```
  default dev eth0  scope link  metric 1000
  169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 169.254.218.78
  169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1000
  192.168.15.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.15.6
  ```

I hope anybody can help me.
Thanks guys

Comment: In test1 the pi and laptop1 have the same IP - this is not good. Laptop2 has an IP in a different subnet -also not good.
Why use zeroconf ip?? Just let the router dhcp handle it?

Comment: Ah yeah this was an issue on the Picture, Laptop 1 have 192.168.15.7 i need this behavior for a customer, like axis ip cameras there are findable over mdns and then a unicast Connection over link local address is used to set the ip, no matter in wich subnet you are